# Serilog writing to undetermined number of log files

Tags: runtime, serilog

I have a bunch of archives, each contains thousands of files to be processed.  I want to write one log file as summary, one containing errors if any, and finally, for each archive, a separate log file with all entries processed.

The first two can be configured with WriteTo and Filters.  But I don't know how many archives up front.  Is it possible to start new log files at runtime in a loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Serilog loggers can be created and destroyed on-the-fly:

```
foreach (var archive in archives)
{
    var filename = "archive-" + archive.Name + ".txt";
    using (var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.File(filename)
            .CreateLogger())
    {
        log.Information("Processing archive");
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Turns out great.  Thanks